# Percentage increase/decrease in two numbers to be multiplied

Tags: fractions, percentages

$A \times B = C $

How do you determine if percentage increase in $A$ and an equivalent decrease percentage decrease in $B$ will result in the same number, bigger or lower numbers.

Many thanks

Comment: It will decrease. $$A\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)B\left(1-\frac{r}{100}\right)=AB\left(1-\frac{r^2}{10000}\right)<AB.$$

Comment: Unless $r=0$ ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: What if, the “r” is different for A and B. And percentage increase exceeds 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Think about the fact that
$$\Big((1+r)A\Big)\cdot\Big((1-r)B\Big) = (1-r^2)\cdot AB$$

This will be less than/greater than/equal to $AB$ precisely when $1-r^2$ is less than/greater than/equal to $1$.

Consider these cases separately to see what must be true of $r$ in each case.

Comment: How would above be different if the value of r is different for A and B?

Comment: And how if percentage increase is more than 100%?

Comment: Well — this was just a hint. Now, *you* think about the questions you pose! Think about how the factors would change, etc.